# Latex background Image Problem [MAC]

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf

I created a latex document. When I open it on Safari/PDF expert is everything ok with the images. When i try to open on chrome the zones without the background shows it a lines...

For example: in Safari :

[image: Safari]

In Chrome :

[image]

Any idea ? Thanks!

Comment: Filipe Welcome to TEXSE, it would be great if you could you give us with your MWE so that we can effectively help you. For more info: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: The quality of the PDF viewers in the browsers vary a lot. Is it still different if you zoom in?

Comment: Yes, I already changed the PNG files to JPEG and every thing seems ok now...